# Merging large amount of polygon-features in script with GDAL/OGR Tools or Python?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, ogr, merge

We have a very large shapefile with over 30000 features and want to merge it with a script on a server. Currently we try it with QGIS, but the processing takes way too much time.

Is there a way to do it with the GDAL/OGR Tools or Python?

Comment: By merge, do you mean to say, change the 30000 features to just one multipart feature?

Comment: yes, thats what I want to do.

Comment: What are those data by the way? How would they be merged? Do they have common fields etc?

Comment: We are working with the OSM-Coastline Polygons, which come from here: [link](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/water-polygons)

Comment: We want to render them in TileMill, but get artefacts at the cutlines, which we want to eliminate by merging the polygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GIS context, the better is organize your data in a database (!).

Then, many kinds of operations will be simple. With PostGIS (using PostgreSQL as database) the command that solves your problem is

```
  SELECT ST_Collect(geom) FROM your30000features_table;
```

And the commands are standard, see standard OGC functions [ST_Collect](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) and [ST_Union](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Union.html).

Using as input "OSM-Coastline Polygons", you are using *POLYGON* OGC types in the database. 
The ST_Collect(geom) of a set of *POLYGONs* will return a *GEOMETRYCOLLECTION*, but  you can convert it into a *MULTIPOLYGON*, or produce it directly by the ST_Union function.

Comment: This seems to be the most viable solution, as I wanted to try PostGIS anyway. I'll try it out right now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome; good decision, try it!   PS: if you are new user in the Stackexchange, remember to click at the check icon in your accepted answer.

Comment: What would be the complete SQL-String for doing this with ST_Union? I just dont get it...

Comment: Hum... Sorry, I "dont get" your question, both are aggregate functions, use the same: 'SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM table'. Perhaps you must check CPU time with 'EXPLAIN SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM table', and compare with ST_collect... And read the guide to check what you need (check also ST_UnaryUnion) about "dissolve boundary" efects.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit undefined. How do I write that into a new table. Yesterday I thought I worked it out, but the resulting table was empty after this: CREATE TABLE water_polygons_merged AS
SELECT
  ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry
FROM water_polygons;

-- Update the geometry_columns table
SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns();

Comment: Ok, it is not about the question, the notes may be deleted after this dialog.  Sugestions:  [1] show me your output of SELECT  count(*), count(CASE WHEN st_issimple(geometry) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) FROM water_polygons;  [2] do the same, but with collect, CREATE TABLE water_polygons_merged0 AS SELECT ST_collect(geometry) AS geometry FROM water_polygons;  [3] ... convert water_polygons_merged0 geometries...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite Python or GDAL but maybe you could try GRASS' [v.extract  function](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass63/v.extract.html). It should let you extract and dissolve the features. You can access it through QGIS' SEXTANTE Toolbox.

Comment: I think trough GRASS I add a lot of overhead to the whole thing. But other things don't work, i'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whether arcmap Python scripting works for you or not but you can check out this topic about batch merging script [here](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1682)

Beside this in python there is a library with the name of [pyshp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) about reading and writing shapefiles.

Comment: Thanks so far. I don' use ArcMap, but give pyshp a try.

Comment: Just a warning though, pyshp is a pure python library so it might be very slow considering the number of features it will have to process.