# Merge (a lot of) features using QGIS or other open source

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mac

I have one shape-file with a lot of features (polygons) and if I try to merge these into one big polygon in QGIS it takes days to complete the merge. So I wonder if there is another way? I saw this question:

[How to "Merge Selected Features" with python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59126/how-to-merge-selected-features-with-python)

The problem is that I don't know python and I have no idea of what they are talking about... So, could someone either give me some advice to perhaps do this operation from command line (I'm using Mac) or maybe if someone has a ready python script that does the trick?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [How to merge a large amount of polygon-features in a script?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33549/how-to-merge-a-large-amount-of-polygon-features-in-a-script)

Comment: Do you just want to copy all the features into one one multipolygon feature, or do you also want to dissolve the polygons?

Comment: Jake, didn't see that one. I'll have a look. Regarding comment #2, I want to dissolve the polygons.